# I am trying to store logs from a file on Hyperledger blockchain and facing these errors

Tags: java, build.gradle, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**LogChain.java**

```
package LogChain;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.Context;

@Contract(
    name = "logchain",
    info = @org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.annotation.Info(
        title = "LogChain",
        description = "Chaincode for storing and retrieving log lines"
    )
)
public class LogChain extends ChaincodeBase implements ContractInterface {

    private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "config.txt";

    @Override
    public Response init(ChaincodeStub stub) {
        // Initialization logic goes here (if any)
        return newSuccessResponse();
    }

    @Override
    @Transaction
    public Response invoke(Context ctx) {
        ChaincodeStub stub = ctx.getStub();
        String function = stub.getFunction();

        if ("storeLogsFromFile".equals(function)) {
            return storeLogsFromFile(stub);
        } else if ("getLogs".equals(function)) {
            return getLogs(stub);
        }

        return newErrorResponse("Invalid function: " + function);
    }

    @Transaction
    public Response storeLogsFromFile(ChaincodeStub stub) {
        try {
            String logFile = readLogFileLocation();

            StringBuilder logLines = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                logLines.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();

            // Store log lines on the blockchain
            stub.putStringState("logLines", logLines.toString());

            return newSuccessResponse("Logs stored successfully");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return newErrorResponse("Failed to read log file location from config file: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return newErrorResponse("Failed to store logs: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Transaction
    public Response getLogs(ChaincodeStub stub) {
        try {
            // Retrieve log lines from the blockchain
            String logLines = stub.getStringState("logLines");

            JSONArray logs = new JSONArray();
            logs.put(logLines);

            return newSuccessResponse(logs.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return newErrorResponse("Failed to get logs: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String readLogFileLocation() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CONFIG_FILE));
        String logFileLocation = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        return logFileLocation;
    }

    private Response newSuccessResponse(String message) {
        return newSuccessResponse(message.getBytes());
    }

    private Response newErrorResponse(String message) {
        return newErrorResponse(message.getBytes());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LogChain().start(args);
    }
}
```

**Build.gradle** file is:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'java-library-distribution'
}

group 'LogChain'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven {
       url "https://hyperledger.jfrog.io/hyperledger/fabric-maven"
    }
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
   
    mavenCentral()
    
    
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java:fabric-chaincode-shim:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java:fabric-chaincode-annotations:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20210307'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.1'

    // Add other dependencies specific to your chaincode project if needed
}

mainClassName = 'org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter'

jar {
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

**Errors** are:

**1. The method invoke(Context) of type LogChain must override or implement a supertype method  LogChain.java   /lib/src/main/java/LogChain line 34 Java Problem :**

```
    @Transaction
    public Response invoke(Context ctx) {
        ChaincodeStub stub = ctx.getStub();
        String function = stub.getFunction();
```

**2. The type LogChain must implement the inherited abstract method ChaincodeBase.invoke(ChaincodeStub) LogChain.java   /lib/src/main/java/LogChain line 22 Java Problem** :

```
public class LogChain extends ChaincodeBase implements ContractInterface {
```

**3.This instance method cannot override the static method from ChaincodeBase   LogChain.java   /lib/src/main/java/LogChain line 94 Java Problem** :

```
private Response newSuccessResponse(String message) {
        return newSuccessResponse(message.getBytes());
    }
```

**4. This instance method cannot override the static method from ChaincodeBase  LogChain.java   /lib/src/main/java/LogChain line 98 Java Problem** :

```
private Response newErrorResponse(String message) {
        return newErrorResponse(message.getBytes());
    }
```

**5. Unresolved dependency: org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java:fabric-chaincode-annotations:2.3.0    LogChain        line 0  Gradle Error Marker**

Please Help!

Comment: Where are you running the fabric network? in VM or Docker container? And can you also share the full stack trace~

Comment: VM, what is stack trace?

Comment: [check this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)